# Why does my search query doesn't turn out well?

Tags: javascript, php

I am tring to make my search function works. It does work but, the result is not true. For example, I search for the word 'data' and it display 'computer programmer'. It suppose to display 'Data Analyst'.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])) {
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search']);
   // $sql = 'SELECT * FROM professional, job, location WHERE J.JOB_ID = P.PROFESSIONAL_ID AND P.PROFESSIONAL_ID = L.LOCATION_ID AND PROFESSIONAL_NAME LIKE '%$search%'';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM professional, job, location WHERE JOB_NAME LIKE '%$search%' AND PROFESSIONAL_ID=JOB_ID AND JOB_ID = LOCATION_ID " ;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $new_result = $row["JOB_NAME"];

    function str_contains($phrase, $word) {
        return strpos($phrase, $word) !== false;
    }

    if (str_contains($new_result,'computer') || str_contains($new_result, 'programmer') || str_contains($new_result, 'computer programmer')) {
        echo "
        <div class= 'expertise'>
        <h2><i class='fa fa-briefcase' aria-hidden='true'></i><a href='computer_programmer.html'> Computer Programmer</a></h2>
        </div>";
    } else if (str_contains($new_result, 'data') || str_contains($new_result, 'analyst') || str_contains($new_result, 'data analyst')) {
        echo "
        <div class= 'expertise'>
        <h2><i class='fa fa-briefcase' aria-hidden='true'></i><a href='data_analyst.html'> Data Analyst</a></h2>
        </div>";
    } else {
        echo 'There are no results matching your search!';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `$result` display `computer programmer`. Correct?

Comment: Yes! Correct! How should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statment is currently incorrect. Currently, your expression will always evaluate to `true` as a non-empty string is considered truthy. Thus your if statement looks more like:

```
if ($result == '%computer%' || true || true) {
```

The above statement will always run the code within the `if` as the expression will always evaluate to true (as `X ∨ T ≡ T`).

Instead, you need to recheck the equality of $result:

```
if ($result == '%computer%' || $result == '%programmer%' || $result == '%computer programmer%') {
  // do "Computer Programer" code...
} else if ($result =='%data%' || $result == '%analyst%' || $result == '%data analyst%') {
 // do "Data Analyst" code...
} else {
  // do "no results code"...
}
```

However, for this to work you need to ensure `$result` is what you think it is and not a `mysqli_result` object

**EDIT**:
To check whether a string contains `computer` or `analyst` etc... you can't use SQL wildcards as you have here. Instead, you can use the PHP method `strpos`. I suggest you build a helper function which will allow you to do this neatly within your if-statement:

```
function str_contains($phrase, $word) {
    return strpos(strtolower($phrase), $word) !== false;
}

// then in your if statement:
if (str_contains($result,'computer') || str_contains($result, 'programmer') || str_contains($result, 'computer programmer')) {
  // do "Computer Programer" code...
} else if (str_contains($result, 'data') || str_contains($result, 'analyst') || str_contains($result, 'data analyst')) {
 // do "Data Analyst" code...
} else {
  // do "no results code"...
}
```

Comment: @NurHidayah That's because `$result` isn't a string like you think it is. You need to get the result properly (eg: using `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);`) And then get the correct column which contains `%compuer%`, %programmer%` etc.. by using `$new_result = $row["columnName]`. `$new_result` is then the variable you should be checking in your if-statment

Comment: $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $new_result = $row["JOB_NAME"];

        if ($new_result == '%computer%' || $new_result == '%programmer%' || $new_result == '%computer programmer%') {
            //do here
          } else if ($new_result =='%data%' || $new_result == '%analyst%' || $new_result == '%data analyst%') {
            echo "
           // do here
          } else {
            // do here
          }
    }

Comment: I have edited my code and it still display 'There are no results matching your search!'

Comment: what do you get if you `echo $new_result` above your `echo "there are no results matching your search!";` in the else?

Comment: It display 'Data Analyst at AS White Global' which is one of the data in the table JOB_NAME

Comment: @NurHidayah if that's the case then `$new_result` doesn't equal anything in any of your `if` statements (eg: `%computer%`, `%analyst%`). Are you trying to see where `$new_result` _contains_ one of these results? Currently, you're checking if the entire string is equal to `$new_result`

Comment: Yes! Currently I'm trying to see where ```$new_result``` contains one of these results

Comment: @NurHidayah I've edited my post. You can use the function I added and the new if statement (you'll need to replace `$result` with `$new_result` for the if-statment)

Comment: you'll need to replace `$result` with `$new_result` for the if-statment

Comment: ```Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function str_pos() in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\search-expertise.php:20 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\php\search-expertise.php(24): str_contains('Data Analyst at...', '%computer%') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\search-expertise.php on line 20```

Comment: It give me error. line 20 is ```return str_pos($a, 'are') !== false;```

Comment: It should be `return strpos($a, 'are') !== false` (no underscore `_`)

Comment: ```Notice: Undefined variable: a in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\search-expertise.php on line 20```
```There are no results matching your search!```  It turns out like this :(

Comment: Woops, sorry that's my bad. I've updated the function again. It should be `return strpos($phrase, $word) !== false;`

Comment: Hmm i don't know why it keeps on display ```There are no results matching your search!```

Comment: ok, I've updated the if statements. You need to remove the `%` around your words

Comment: It still display ```There are no results matching your search!``` Hmm can you check the source code that I've edited? I'll edit in my question.

Comment: Ok, but maybe first try modifying your function so it returns the following: `return strpos(strtolower($phrase), $word) !== false;`

Comment: Hi there! Can u help me to solve this problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56418156/how-to-make-a-radiobutton-read-a-variable-from-php

Answer (score 1):

You are using $result wrong in code
See

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])) {
        $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search']);
       // $sql = 'SELECT * FROM professional, job, location WHERE J.JOB_ID = P.PROFESSIONAL_ID AND P.PROFESSIONAL_ID = L.LOCATION_ID AND PROFESSIONAL_NAME LIKE '%$search%'';
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM professional, job, location WHERE JOB_NAME LIKE '%$search%' AND PROFESSIONAL_ID=JOB_ID AND JOB_ID = LOCATION_ID " ;
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                if ($row['JOB_NAME'] == '%computer%' || '%programmer%' || '%computer programmer%')
                {
                echo "
                <div class= 'expertise'>
                <h2><i class='fa fa-briefcase' aria-hidden='true'></i><a href='computer_programmer.html'> Computer Programmer</a></h2>
                </div>";
                }
                else if ($row['JOB_NAME'] =='%data%' || '%analyst%' || '%data analyst%'){
                    echo "
                <div class= 'expertise'>
                <h2><i class='fa fa-briefcase' aria-hidden='true'></i><a href='data_analyst.html'> Data Analyst</a></h2>
                </div>";
                }
        }

        } else {
            echo 'There are no results matching your search!';
        }
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: professional in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\search-expertise.php on line 17. It display this. Line 17 is, if ($row........

Comment: that is problem with field name your field name is JOB_NAME so change in code replace $row['professional'] with $row['JOB_NAME']

Comment: It still display 'computer programmer', not 'data analyst' when i search for data.